# FLEX: how can I detect visual collisions between objects?

Tags: apache-flex

I would like to avoid the tags overlapping each other in this small Flex project:
I've this small FLEX project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/IVbeta1/main.html#

The items are LinkButtons. How can I check if they are colliding or not ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `hitTestObject` as seen [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/langref/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()) is what you're looking for. Then you can see if objects overlap and can change their positions accordingly.

Comment: do I have to place them on the canvas before to check if they overlap right ? I guess I'm going to have some flickering...

Comment: I meant, any TWO DisplayObject instances.

Comment: @Patrick, as to whether they have to be on the Canvas, you can also try placing them somewhere totally off the Canvas or making them visible=false.... I'd have to fire up my Flex IDE to tell you which would work, and today is not my Flex day.